# How to Parse Abbreviated Day of Week String to DayofWeek

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string of abbreviated days of week e.g. "M Tu W Th F". I need to parse it to DayOfWeek.

Let's say I've converted the string to an array of strings. How do I parse each of those values to DayOfWeek?

Is there a way to do this without a custom function?

I'm aware of the method below for standard "Monday,"Tuesday"...." but how do we use that with the above shortened format?

```
var EnumDay = ((DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), "M"));
```

Comment: I would just use a `switch` statement. Or a switch expression if you're using a modern version of C#

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there was some way to do this without a custom function.

Comment: @CaesarTex - Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't parse those using the framework directly. Instead, you need something like a `switch` statement, or a switch expression if you are using a modern version of C#. For example:

```
public DayOfWeek Parse(string value)
{
    return value switch
    {
        "M" => DayOfWeek.Monday,
        "Tu" => DayOfWeek.Tuesday,
        "W" => DayOfWeek.Wednesday,
        "Th" => DayOfWeek.Thursday,
        "F" => DayOfWeek.Friday,
        _ => throw new Exception("Not a valid day of the week, or maybe it's a weekend, go outside and play")
    };
}
```

And use like this:

```
var day = Parse("Th");
```

Comment: Thanks. That works but I was trying to avoid a custom function.

Comment: @CaesarTex - Why?